# Should operator>> clear a container?

Tags: c++, refactoring, iostream

I'm refactoring some code that reads containers of integers from files. I've moved the common code into stream extractors like these:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, std::vector<int> &list);
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, std::map<int, std::vector<int>> &graph);
```

My question is whether these functions should clear the containers before writing, or just insert/append data to them. (In my particular case, it doesn't matter, but in the interest of code reuse, I'd like to know.)

Is there a convention in C++ for these situations? I'm trying to code according to the Principle of Least Surprise.

Comment: Are these containers used somewhere else before? If yes probably they should be cleared.

Comment: No, there is none - mine is append

Comment: My opinion is that it'd be least surprising to the caller if you didn't go about clearing data that they may wanted preserved in the container.

Comment: Also, I think these operators are too general, I would not implement these.

Comment: Please read [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421708/3204551): It explicitly warns that *only if the semantics are absolutely clear without reading the code / documentation should you overload an operator*. Bit-shifting streams is in that category only because the standard library does it, so pay extra attention to what it does.

Comment: @quasardonkey _'Should operator>> clear a container?'_ I would expect so ...

Comment: IIRC technically you are not allowed to overload anything in `std` unless explicitly allowed to do so. So this would be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extraction operators provided by the standard library all **replace the target variable's contents**.

Including `std::string`, which is a container type, like your examples.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if it only applied to simple data types. I forgot about string.